# Using forward slash in java servlet for print html code with StringBuilder or PrintWriter

Tags: java, html, servlets, stringbuilder, printwriter

when I print the output of a servlet to html, does not work any code that carry forward slash, for example:

```
StringBuilder htmlOut = new StringBuilder();
htmlOut.append("<body style='background-image: url('images/background.jpg');'>");
```

anything that leads forward slash does not work in html. What is the correct way to pass forward to html slash through the servlet with StringBuilder or PrintWriter?,
thanks

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean "backslash" as that is an escape character in Java. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't to do with the `/` itself, it's that you've got 4 single quotes in that string, meaning that `images/background.jpg` is part of the body tag, not the `style` attribute.

It may be the case that the browser can "guess what you meant" without a `/`; but the `/` throws it off.

Try changing the outer ones to double-quotes (escaping them will be necessary):

```
htmlOut.append("<body style=\"background-image: url('images/background.jpg');\">");
                            ^^ Here, and the corresponging closing quote.
```

Comment: This example does not work:   htmlOut.append("<body background= 'images/background.jpg'>");

Comment: in my JSP work this:  < body background="images/background.jpg">

Comment: @AngelPicallo because of the space after the `=`? Because of using `'` vs `"`? This is nothing to do with Java, you're just generating invalid HTML.

Comment: but in my servlet out not work:  htmlOut.append("<body background= 'images/background.jpg'>");

Comment: and in my servlet this work:  htmlOut.append("<body bgcolor= '#535c7b'>");